# Querying multiple collections and documents from mongodb and outputting results in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb

Hi all I have the following collections in mongodb: companies, devices, people, and  research_groups. These are the structures of the collections:

for people:

```
_id:ObjectId(6005e087ebbf3481167a06b0)

bio:"some bio"

contentTeam:true

devTeam:true

firstName:"Michael"

github:"https://github.com/some_user"

lastName:"some_lastname"

lastUpdate:2021-02-09T00:48:00.000+00:00

preferredName:null

queryName:"michael-some_lastname"

researchGroupId:ObjectId(5f25138723830635041c0d1c)

role:"Assistant Professor"

twitter:
"https://twitter.com/some_user"

verifiedTeam:true

website:"some_website.com"

yearsActiveEnd:null

yearsActiveStart:2021
```

for the companies collection we have the following structure:

```
_id:objectID(6006693bf3f4e407b49a9861)

CEO:"some ceo"

authorId:Array

city:"some City"

collaborators:Array

coordinates:Array

country:

"some country"

devices:Array

founders:null

intro:"some basic intro to be displayed"

lastUpdate:2021-02-09T20:40:00.000+00:00

name:"Some name Corporation"

queryName:"a-queryname"

verifiedId:Array

website:null

yearDissolved:null

yearFounded:2016
```

for devices we have the following structure:

```
_id:ObjectID(5f47fd159905ade393a6ff49)

authorId:Array

background:"Some background about the device..."

ceMarkYear:2016

clinicalTrials:Array

commercialPartnersId:Array

elecDiameter:"70"

elecLayout:null

elecNumber:"1600"

elecPitch:null

endOfProductionYear:2019

fdaApprovalYear:null

firstPatientYear:"1999"

imageProcessorLocation:"some string"

implantLocation:"some string"

lastUpdate:2021-02-09T20:40:00.000+00:00

name:"Some string"

numImplantedToDate:null

queryName:"some-query"

researchGroupsId:Array

status:"inactive"

summary:"some summary of the product that is going on"

verified lookup:"#VALUE!"

verifiedId:Array

videoLink:null
```

and finally for research_groups we have the following structure:

```
_id:ObjectID(5f45582749fb0555618598ee)

authorId:Array

collaborators:Array

director:"director name"

intro:"Some intros about what we are looking at"

lastUpdate:2021-01-30T03:14:00.000+00:00

name:"Name of the research group"

queryName:"blah"

universityId:ObjectID(5f3b4a2593817722db9c377c)

verifiedId:ObjectID(6022dd609f2f2fb91753ba31)

website:"somewebsiteuniversity.com"
```

Now the actual problem:

I am working in react on a webpage, I would like to access the collection "people" and for each "_id" in people, I would like to search the collections "companies", "devices" and "research_groups" and get the total times that the "_id" from the "people" collection is an "authorID" in "companies", "devices" and "research_groups"(so the number of times a given "_id" appears as "authorID" in "devices" + the number of times it appears as "authorID" in "companies" + the number of times it appears as "authorID" in "research_groups").

How can I implement this in mongoDB and render this result in react? Note: I already have the connection and set up established in react and am simply wanting to display the result as a number on a webpage.

Comment: _"How can I most effectively implement this in mongoDB"_ - please note that this is asking for opinions. Consider showing the effort you have made so far as a [mcve]?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I agree however my efforts are pretty off the mark and "corrections" on my effort would be a complete novel solution, further providing an attempt at solution might frame the responses in the direction of my thinking; which I didn't want . I am interested in garnishing the opinions of those more experience because it provides more learning opportunities rather than just having a solution given.

Comment: Then may you consider asking for specific help? Things like "best", "most efficient", and the like, will lead to opinionated answers. It's always a good idea to include past efforts, no matter how off the mark you may think they are